# C++ void return type of main()

Tags: c++

Some C++ compilers allow the main function to have return type `void`.  But doesn't the Operating System require `int` type value returned to specify whether the program ended well or not?

Comment: Where did you learn this? C++ requires `main` to have a return type of `int`.

Comment: @dirkgently: It's wrong about C. 5.1.2.2.1 bulet point 1 specifically allowes for main to be defined in "some other implementation defined manner".  Also 5.1.2.2.3 starts with the phrase "If the return type of the main function is a type compatible with int" which implies main does not have to return int.

Comment: From the same clause: _It shall be defined with a return type of int_. The part you quote is considered to be a defect by some experts: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/msg/7340b025f5fe8657 and http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/c1a1cc0a23af7227. Finally, there are other areas of the Standard that are implementation dependent and it is advisable not to mess with these for a strictly compliant program. A conforming program is anything that a conforming implementation accepts -- but that doesn't make `void main` any more correct.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

C++ does *not* allow `main` to have a `void` return type. The published C++ standard requires it to be `int`. Some C++ compilers allow you to use `void`, but that's not recommended. In general, the OS doesn't care one way or the other. A specific OS might require a program to give a return value, but it doesn't necessarily have to come from `main`'s return value. If the C++ compiler allows `void`, then it probably provides some other means of specifying the program's exit code.

Answer (score 20):

> C++ allows main function to have return type void

**No, it doesn't.**

The C++ standard only requires 2 different types of main signatures.  Others may be optionally added if the return type is `int`.

Implementations of C++ which allow void return types are incorrect in terms of  the C++ standard.

*C++03 standard S. 3.6.1-2:*

> An implementation shall not predefine the main function. 
>   This function shall not be overloaded. It shall
>   have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.
>   All implementations shall allow both
>   of the following definitions of main:
>
> ```
> int main() { /* ... */ } 
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {/* ... */ }
> ```

If you want portable C++ code, or to write good C++ examples then you should always use one of the 2 variations above.

Answer (score 5):

`main` returning `void` is accepted for backwards compatibility, but it is not legal.

In this case, the exit code will be 0. You can still change the exit code, using exit function.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard does not allow main() to have a return type of void. Most compilers will let it pass for historical reasons, though.

Answer (score 3):

In languages where a `void` return from main is legal (not C++), the OS usually sees a return value of `0` on normal (non-exceptional) program termination.

Answer (score 1):

That's why void main() is not allowed by standard C++ - though some compilers (e.g. gcc) does allow it.

To make it short: always use int main(), never void main().

Comment: gcc allows it for C but forbid it for C++, even if you tell it to be -fpermissive.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the compiler, you may be able to use a void main function, however the proper way (that a truly standard compliant compiler should follow) is to return int with 0 being a nice & clean exit and anything else indicating that your program has done something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

```
But doesn't OS require int type value returned to specify whether program 
ended well or not?
```

Why would it always? On windows when you double click on the icon, the process dies after it ends. OS do not check for the return type there. Even on linux if you just run the binary as ./runBinary, it simply runs and exits. The OS do not show message by itself that it fails or succeeds.

All the above answers are right that the standard says it is int, but some compilers allow void too.