# Can This Code Compile?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [C++ void return type of main()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652182/c-void-return-type-of-main)
>   [What is the proper declaration of main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main)

Simple question, really.

My friend and I are perusing the Powerpoint slides of a professor we are supposed to be hearing next semester. It will be a Java course. For some reason, he has this C++ code snippet

```
#include <iostream.h>
main ()
{ cout << "Hello, World\n"; }
```

I have told my friend, "No, this won't work with any modern C++ compiler."

My question is now, can this compile at all?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: A better duplicate would be [What is the proper declaration of `main()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207134/what-is-the-proper-declaration-of-main) but it's still not quite a duplicate, I suppose.

Answer (score 21):

It could, sure.

Consider, for example, if `<iostream.h>` was a header with the following contents:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
#define main int main
```

Comment: Is it definitely allowed to `#define` `main` to something else?

Comment: @Mark: Sure. It's just an identifier; there's nothing special about it as an identifier unless it's used as the name of a function in the global namespace.

Comment: Or of course the last line of "iostream.h" could just be `int` ;-)

Comment: @Steve:  Oh, that's an even better idea!

Answer (score 7):

That is not standard C++. The list of issues is quite long for a piece of code that short... probably because it comes from ages ago and an old non-conforming compiler.

- The proper name of the include header is `#include <iostream>`, the `.h` was dropped during the ANSI standarization.
- Types must be explicitly stated in C++. You cannot declare a function without return type and get a default `int` (that is C, not C++).
- The standard signatures for main are: `int main()`, and `int main( int argc, char** )` (implementations can provide extra arguments, but the return type must be `int`)
- `cout` is defined inside the `std` namespace and cannot be used without qualification unless you add a `using`.

The equivalent code in proper C++ would be

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
   std::cout << "Hello world\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will compile, though any decent compiler should raise a warning. Since you're using `#include <iostream.h>`, the compiler assumes that this is old code and compiles it in backwards-compatible mode. On my machine, gcc says:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/iostream.h:31,
                 from oldcpp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning:
#warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. 
Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ 
standard. Examples include substituting the <X> header for the <X.h> header for C++ 
includes, or <iostream> instead of the deprecated header <iostream.h>. 
To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.
```

But it still compiles it fine. On running the code, I get exactly what is expected: i.e.:

```
Hello, World
```

Comment: That should not compile in any conforming compiler. C++ does not allow for implicit return types, and the signature of main returns an `int`. Many compilers still allow the obsolete .h headers, but the missing return type should be a show stopper. Then again, g++ seems to accept it by default, but will warn with -Wall or -pedantic

Comment: There *is* a good reason for this. Though this is not correct according to standard C++, this would have been valid code pre-standardization. To prevent really old code from breaking, most compilers should still compile this with a warning unless explicitly not to.

Comment: @dribeas: conforming compilers are permitted to compile non-standard code, provided that they emit a diagnostic. So it's not correct to say it "shouldn't compile". It shouldn't compile *cleanly*.

Answer (score 1):

Is this even worth questioning? Why write corner-case C/C++? What's wrong with keeping with the standards? `main()` is the entry point of the program, and the OS expects a return code from the program. Now there are arguments whether `void main()` is acceptable, but why even defend it? Just use `int main()` and be a happy dude that writes good code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I start **every** program with this (without the HW! then) and never ever had any issues.