# Scope of new memory in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I try to do the following I get an error saying I'm trying to read or write to protected memory.

```
void func1(int * ptr) {
    int *ptr_b = new int[5];
    ptr = ptr_b; 
}

void main() {
    int *ptr_a;
    func1(ptr_a);
    delete [] ptr_a;
}
```

Is this legal?

Comment: Don't use `void main()`: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main. You should be passing the pointer by reference to start with though.

Comment: [void main](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3652182/14065)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  You're making a common beginner mistake.  You're not remembering that pointers are just variables that are passed by value unless you ask for a reference or pointer to them.  Change the signature of your function to `void func1(int *& ptr)`

Answer (score 8):

Change your signature to:

```
void func1(int *& ptr)
```

You're passing the pointer by value, so the outside `ptr` doesn't get changed. So it's like doing

```
int main() {  // <--- main returns int
    int *ptr_a;
    delete [] ptr_a;
}
```

which is illegal, since `ptr_a` is not initialized.

Comment: I mean, seeing as how `void main()` isn't legal C++, we should be providing examples *with* legal C++. See the link in the question comments for what I mean.

Answer (score 4):

You passed the pointer by *value*. Which means that the pointer that the function works with is a local copy of the caller's pointer. And so the value you assign in the function cannot seen by the caller.

Pass it by *reference* instead so that the function can assign to the caller's pointer rather than assigning to a local copy.

```
void func1(int* &ptr)
```

Or, perhaps consider returning the newly allocated pointer:

```
int* func1()
{
    return new int[5];
}
```

I'd prefer the latter approach.